# INotifyDataErrorInfo Possible to use this in .net40 clr rather than the silverlight one

Tags: .net, silverlight-4.0, interface

This interface is great on the silverlight front end - at least in theory.

However i would really liek the validation to also be bael to execute in the .net40 version of the clr so that i can reuse the validation code.

I realise that this is probably a futile question, but nothing ventured nothing gained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not available in .Net as [the doc page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo%28VS.95%29.aspx) shows.

Comment: that was a bad question ... I will never know if the answer is final. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnNicholas: Unless MS hides things from us then it's final. But you could probably get the SL source and roll your own with that as guidance.

Comment: thats nto a bad idea ... i ended up going wtih fluent as it has libraries for both clr's